# How to bind a style to a control in a View's code-behind?

Tags: maui, code-behind

I have some styles and I want to set them in the code-behind of my View.

How can I bind them in C#?

*My Styles:*

```xml
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="choosenButton" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Shadow" Value="10" />
        <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="None" />
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="nonChoosenButton" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Shadow" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold" />
    </Style>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

I'm looking for something like this *(pseudo code)*:

```cs
private void SetUpView()
{
    switch (_calendarView)
    {
        case CalendarEnums.CurrentCalendarView.Liste:
            MyButton.Style = "{Binding choosenButton}"; // How it should look like???
            break;
        case CalendarEnums.CurrentCalendarView.Monat:
            SecondButton.Style = "{Binding nonChoosenButton}"; // How it should look like???
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are actually looking for DataTriggers. Or maybe VisualStates. Definitely not "style binding". Also, direct access to controls is not recommended. Use modern architectures like MVVM.

Answer (score 1):

One way you can apply your style is by overriding `OnBindingContextChanged()` in the code-behind, which is working for me:

```cs
protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
{
    base.OnBindingContextChanged();
    // Apply your style, for example I am applying it to a button
    myButton.SetDynamicResource(Button.StyleProperty, "YourStyleName");
}
```

Note that you should add `x:Name="myButton"` to your control in the XAML part.

Comment: Why in `OnBindingContextChanged()`?

Answer (score 1):

To set a style with `Key` `"buttonStyleKey"` in `Resources` in C#:

XAML Resources in a `ContentPage`:

```xml
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="buttonStyleKey" TargetType="Button">
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

Code-behind:

```cs
if (Resources.TryGetValue("buttonStyleKey", out object value) && 
    value is Style buttonStyle)
{
    Button button = new Button
    {
        Style = buttonStyle
    };
}
```

Comment: Maybe show how to apply this to the specific cases in the question, e.g. `MyButton.Style` and `SecondButton.Style`.